# referencing objects' object

Tags: java, android

First off, I'm trying to make a tetris clone on android, for the learning experience, I've already accomplished this, but the code was a horrible mess and decided to finally go back and clean it up since I knew more about what was going on.

But now it seems that one of my constructors are not getting executed...

I'm getting an NPE when referencing something that should have been initialized in the constructor, first set as a global variable. It's failing on this piece of code:

```
blocksWorld.blockoid.parts.size()
```

I set up the object for BlocksWorld in my GameScreen's constructor, which does get executed:

```
public GameScreen(Game game) {
    super(game);
    this.screen = AndroidGame.GAME_SCREEN;
    blocksWorld = new BlocksWorld();
}
```

and this is the constructor of BlocksWorld which does not seem to be getting executed:

```
public BlocksWorld() {
    // resets the game world
    for (int x = 0; x < WORLD_WIDTH; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < WORLD_HEIGHT; y++) {
            grid[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
    NewBlockoid(blockoid);
}
```

NewBlockoid:

```
public void NewBlockoid(Blockoid blockoid) {
    nextPiece = random.nextInt(7) + 1;
    blockoid = new Blockoid(grid, nextPiece);
}
```

Blockoid's constructor:

```
public Blockoid(int[][] grid, int blockoidType) {
    this.grid = grid;
    this.blockoidType = blockoidType;
    switch (blockoidType) {
    case Blockoid.I:
        color = Color.CYAN;
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 1));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 2));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 3));
        break;
    case Blockoid.J:
        color = Color.BLUE;
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 1));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 2));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(4, 2));
        break;
    case Blockoid.L:
        color = Color.rgb(255, 165, 0);
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 1));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 2));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(6, 2));
        break;
    case Blockoid.O:
        color = Color.YELLOW;
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 1));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(6, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(6, 1));
        break;
    case Blockoid.S:
        color = Color.GREEN;
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 1));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(4, 1));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(6, 0));
        break;
    case Blockoid.T:
        color = Color.rgb(128, 0, 128);
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(4, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(6, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 1));
        break;
    case Blockoid.Z:
        color = Color.RED;
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(5, 1));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(4, 0));
        parts.add(new BlocksParts(6, 1));
        break;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what's wrong? Is more code needed? Thank you for your help...

Comment: What does this do: `NewBlockoid(blockoid);`?  (Hint: It doesn't update blokoid.)

Comment: @HotLicks hmmm? sounds like you're holding back? :D